# Need help in understanding Scale

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm using the dc.js library to create a composite chart. Here's what I have for my chart setup:

```
 chartCountMonths
    .height(350)
    .x(d3.scaleTime())
    .xUnits(d3.timeMonths)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .compose([chartCurrentYear,chartPreviousYear]);
  chartCurrentYear
    .dimension(monthDim)
    .colors('orange')
    .dashStyle([10, 2])
      .title(function (d) { var t = yearCurrent + ": " + numFormat(d.value.current) + '\n' + yearPrev + ": " + numFormat(d.value.previous); return t })
    .group(monthGroupByYear, "Year " + yearCurrent)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.value.current })
chartPreviousYear
      .dimension(monthDim)
      .colors('green')
      .title(function (d) { var t = yearCurrent + ": " + numFormat(d.value.current) + '\n' + yearPrev + ": " + numFormat(d.value.previous); return t })
      .group(monthGroupByYear, "Year " + yearPrev)
      .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.value.previous });
```

It's maddening to me that I don't fully understand the scaling of d3 / dc.js. What the above code renders is this:
[image]

The object I've created, using reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial is this:

```
 [
    {"key":"07","value":{"current":900,"previous":963}},
    {"key":"08","value":{"current":779,"previous":577}},
    {"key":"09","value":{"current":457,"previous":651}},
    {"key":"10","value":{"current":0,"previous":646}},
    {"key":"11","value":{"current":0,"previous":621}},
    {"key":"12","value":{"current":0,"previous":1}},
    {"key":"06","value":{"current":1016,"previous":827}}
]
```

So i guess I'm missing how to work make this scale work. I just kind of play with the scale methods until something works.
Can anyone point me to the solution of this, and give me links to understand scale in general? I swear I spend more time on figuring out the scaling ( xUnits() and .x) than any other part of this library :)

FYI: the key comes from d.Month, where I use d3.timeFormat("%m") to format the date into the two-digit month.

I was trying to get `tickFormat()` to work but `d3.time.format("%B")` produces the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.getMonth is not a function
```

HERE's the codepen:  https://codepen.io/jlbmagic/pen/QWEEpOB

THANKS

Comment: Can you please change your code to be a runnable [mre]? You can use a snippet, it will help produce better answers

Comment: You are not the only one: d3 scales are confusing to everyone at first, especially time scales. Your immediate problem is that your keys should be JavaScript dates if you want `d3.scaleTime` to work. Since you are overlaying years, a better option might be an ordinal scale and `xUnits`. It looks like you are currently getting milliseconds because JS dates are milliseconds underneath.

Comment: I.e. it is likely that you are getting 07, 08, 09, 10ms on Jan 1 1970 because that is where JS times start. It's possible to make your stuff work with dates but D3 and dc.js don't have any concept of "months within any year" so you would be mapping all your dates to an arbitrary year. That's why I would suggest an ordinal, or maybe better linear, scale.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. You're incredibly helpful. I'll work through it here. Thanks. What i'm trying to do is group by month, so that's why I did the numbers. I wonder if the scaleTime and timeMonths(?) scales would help me with this.

Comment: You haven't shown your crossfilter code, but you can group by month by changing your dimension or group key function to return the month. The D3 functions round down to the nearest time interval, not really necessary for this. [Date.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) should do the job. If you're still stuck, please edit your question to add enough code to repro.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks. I'll update the question with a repo. I've gone through so many versions of dc/Crossfilter/D3 to get it to work in IE 11. (that's a stupid requirement–don't get me started). I have a working version and I'll update this, using dc 2.0 (arg). I'm gonna see how far up the dc version ladder i get while sticking on D3 v3

Comment: That’s odd - I tested IE up to dc@3.1.8, and d3@5 should be fine. crossfilter supported IE through 1.4.*

Comment: Hmm. Okay. I'll keep working through it here. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the codepen.io in the question. I was trying to get the tick() to work but couldn't. Seems like it can't work on a composite chart??  I still think I'm missing stuff. LOL. I'll try higher versions tomorrow. I'm using FileMaker (a database-file creator) to render a chart using JS code, and on Windows, the FileMaker platform uses IE11 to run code inside the database file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in comments, it's indeed confusing to deal with dates and know when you should use numbers or strings instead.

The specific problem you are running into is with

overviewComposite.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B"));

This crashes because the X values are the strings (ordinals) `'01'`, `'02'`...

If you use a time scale, then all of your data and accessors will work with dates, but here I think it's best just to map the numbers back to months manually:

```
const monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
overviewComposite.xAxis().tickFormat(m => monthNames[+m - 1]);
```

(`+m` converts the string to a number. -1 is because months are numbered starting at 1.)

[Fork of your codepen](https://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/JjKKwad).

[image]

Comment: Got it thanks. I'll do that. Now i'm trying to get a stacked composite bar (the client prefers row) chart. I need to stay in Dc / Cross filter every day for the rest of my life so I don't forget everything I learned in a previous project.

Comment: Yep, I know about the cost of context switching. This is one of four projects of similar complexity that I juggle each day. It can be painful. Sorry there is no stacked row chart in dc.js. There should be, but no one has gotten it working to my knowledge.